# How to inspect an iOS app with appium on a Windows machine

Tags: appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I need to inspect an IPA with Appium Inspector.  Is there a way to do this on a Windows machine?  I'm looking for free and easy.  The only option i've found is putting OSX into VMWare on Windows which seems like overkill just to inspect an app.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done from Windows. Using OSX is the only option.

Comment: Thanks Anish.  Any suggestions on how to get on OSX keeping things free or cost low?  I need OSX to periodically get the element stack of my app from appium and thats it.  Amounting to maybe minutes each month.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about this. I have never used OSX much and don't know if there are trial versions or any other low cost approach.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox and instructions here worked perfect.  And free.

https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc-on-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0):

To inspect an ios app it should be opened in simulator.In windows you cannot use ios simulators.So you need to have mac because you cannot even automate the app from windows machine using appium.

Answer (score 0):

Use Appium inspector with Cloud device provider